# How to get Material-UI AutoComplete renderOption to work for selected value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, material-ui, redux-form

Material-UI Autocomplete component let's you use an array of options and transform the options like so:

You have an array of option objects: `[{option}, {option}.....{option}]`

I use the prop function `renderOption={option => option.title}` to have the list of options be the options' titles, and I want to use the options' ids as the actual value to pass to the form handler so I use the built in function `` getOptionLabel={option => `${option.id}`} ``. This works until I select an option. The text in the input shows the id, not the title. How do I get the input's label to be the option's title, and still pass the id as the value?

The field

````
       ```
         <Field
            classes={classes}
            name={field}
            label={titleCase(field)}
            InputLabelProps={{
              classes: {
                root: classes.label,
                shrink: 'shrink'
              }
            }}
            component={renderAutoCompleteDataField}
            renderOption={(option )=> option[fieldProp]}
            getOptionLabel={(option =>  `${option.id}`)}
            options={choices}
          />
````

The renderAutoCompletefunction

```
export const renderAutoCompleteDataField = ({ options, nonfilter, renderOption, getOptionSelected, getOptionLabel, classes, input, onChange, label, fullWidth, value, defaultValue, ...custom }) => {
  return (
          <Autocomplete
          options={options}
          getOptionLabel={getOptionLabel}
          renderOption= {renderOption}
          getOptionSelected={getOptionSelected}
          onSelect={onChange}
          classes={{ 
            listbox: classes.listbox, 
            input: classes.input, 
            option: classes.option 
          }}
          renderInput={(params) => (
            <TextField
            {...params}
            label={label}
            size="small"
            color="secondary"
            variant="outlined"
            fullWidth={fullWidth}
            InputProps={{
              ...params.InputProps,
              className: classes.listbox,
              input: classes.input

            }}
            InputLabelProps={{ className: classes.label }}
            {...input}
            {...custom}
            />
          )}/>

 )
}
```